# Need xml component supporting D2009

Tags: xml, delphi, delphi-2009

I'm looking for a xml component/Library which supporting Delphi 2009.

Thanks!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Delphi ships with TXMLDocument, which is a wrapper that lets you choose between MSXML, Open XML and Xerces XML.

I just import Microsoft's MSXML and use it directly.

Under Component|Import Component..., select Type Library and browse to Microsoft XML.  I recommend 6.0, but you can use 4 if you like.  Avoid 3 as it wasn't very compliant with the XML standard and very early versions leak memory, and version 5 is only available with Office.

**Update**

If speed is a big concern, you might want to take a look at SAX (Simple API for XML), which streams the XML instead of building the DOM in memory.  This used to be included in MSXML, but I thought I read somewhere that it had been removed in version 6.  I usually use the DOM, so I can't recommend a specific SAX parser, but a quick search on [SourceForge](http://sourceforge.net/search/?type_of_search=soft&words=delphi+sax) returns some options.

Comment: Yes, I know TXMLDocument, but its processing speed is too slow. 
I just need to generate XML content, and parse XML content, I need the speed to be fast.

Comment: Then I'd look at importing MSXML (instead of using it through TXMLDocument), which is quite fast for DOM processing.  If speed is your biggest issue and/or you have really big XML files, look at SAX instead.  I'll update my answer.

Answer (score 6):

As far as I know [OmniXML](http://www.omnixml.com) fully supports D2009.

Answer (score 2):

The Open XML, Alternative Document Object Model (**ADOM**) is also a great (and 100% Delphi, no ActiveX/COM dependencies) XML library.

It supports Delphi 5, 6, 7, 8, 2005, 2006, 2007 and 2009.

http://www.philo.de/xml/downloads.shtml

Answer (score 2):

[NativeXML](http://www.simdesign.nl/xml.html) from SimDesign supports Delphi 2 -> Delphi 2010.

- It's native delphi so needs no external dlls.
- Free with source.
- Premium support (forum/email) can be purchased.
- Purchasing gives access to more frequent updates/bug fixes etc.
- Comes with documentation and examples.

Before finding NativeXML, I looked at several other XML solutions. Some didn't work. Most seemed overly difficult to use compared to my modest XML needs. I only need to parse small XML files for configuration info etc.

In practice I've found NativeXML well designed and easy to use. I strongly recommend checking it out!

Answer (score 1):

What about msxml that is included in Delphi2007 ?
I assume it also works in D2009.

Answer (score 1):

Delphi includes TXMLDocument / IXMLDocument which can use MSXML and other parsers. What else do you need?